# Supabase auth Facebook error: Error getting user email from external provider

Tags: supabase

I'm trying to test out my Nuxt app with Facebook login but I keep getting an error on the address bar:

`?error=server_error&error_description=Error+getting+user+email+from+external+provider#_=_`

No other errors on the console. I got all set up: Facebook app, Facebook advanced access on `email` and `public_profile`, callback URLs, app ID, and keys. It would go through Facebook's auth page then it redirects to my localhost with the error. User won't be registered to `auth.users` as well.

```js
const supabase = useSupabaseAuthClient();
const socialAuth = async (provider) => {
  const { error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({ provider: provider });
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Social Auth success.");
  }
};
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="socialAuth('facebook')">Login with Facebook</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

I've tried posting this in their GitHub discussions but I haven't received an answer from the community so far.

Comment: Are you able to run it after passing scopes? 

`socialAuth('facebook', 'public_profile email')`, then add scopes to the function calling the signInWithOAuth method?

Comment: @Mansueli I tried this. The error was gone but I still can't log in with Facebook. URL has `#_=_` on the end though. I checked the logs on Supabase and still the same error `unable to find email with Facebook provider`.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Even when passing the scopes to the function call the seem to be ignored.

Comment: @ThomasValadez I raised this [issue](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue/issues/936#issuecomment-1434148654) and their only response is that it's a Facebook issue. Since Supabase Auth heavily relies on having a user email, I have no workaround for this but to use another provider.